# passing data to infowindowclick google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I've declared current location latlong and selected location latlong. I want to pass these latlong to `onInfoWindowClick()`. 
When I try to use `Toast` to get the data that I set from `marker.setTag(mLatitude)` and `marker.seTag(mLongitude)`, It give me the same data only `mLongitude`. Can anyone help me, please.
This is my code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() != "-- Pilih ATM --"){

                    mMap.clear();

                    String pilih_atm = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
//                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pilih_atm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM atm WHERE atm_name = '" + pilih_atm + "'",null);
                    if (cursor != null){
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                            title = cursor.getString(1).toString();
                            __global_endposition = cursor.getString(2).toString();
                            String[] exp_endCoordinate = __global_endposition.split(",");
                            double lat_endposition = Double.parseDouble(exp_endCoordinate[0]);
                            double lng_endposition = Double.parseDouble(exp_endCoordinate[1]);
                            LatLng endx = new LatLng(lat_endposition, lng_endposition);

                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                            options.position(endx);
                            options.title(title);
                            options.snippet(__global_endposition);
                            if (title.equals("ATM BNI")){
                                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                            }else if(title.equals("ATM BCA")){
                                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                            }else if(title.equals("ATM Mandiri")){
                                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
                            }

                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                            marker.setTag(mLatitude);
                            marker.setTag(mLongitude);

                            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(getActivity()));

                            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                                    // I want to get current location LatLong and selected location LatLong
                                    // I want execute the LatLong on this method

                                    // this just for testing
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LatLng: "+marker.getTag()+", "+marker.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
                            cursor.close();
                            cursor = null;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [`Marker`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) object has only one `Tag` object and when you call [`.setTag()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) second time, you overrides previously set tag object:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
marker.setTag(mLatitude);          // tag = mLatitude
marker.setTag(mLongitude);         // tag overrides, and now tag = mLongitude
```

The one of solution is:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
marker.setTag("" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);    // tag now is string: "mLatitude, mLongitude"
```